# Application of implicit function theorem?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, manifolds

Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function in the open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$(x^2+y^4)f(x,y)+f(x,y)^3 = 1, \forall (x,y) \in U$$
Show that $f$ is of class $C^1$ in $U$.

I think that is an application of implicit function theorem, but I don't know how to solve it, because I only saw examples about system of linear equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicit function theorem would apply directly to tell you that if you have the equation
$$F(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^4)z + z^3 = 1,$$
then you can locally solve for $z=f(x,y)$ near $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ as a $C^1$ function provided

(1) $F$ is $C^1$ (it is)

(2) $\partial F/\partial z \ne 0$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

What do you notice about $\partial F/\partial z$ at every point in $U$?

Comment: I used the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (0,0,1)$, and so $det (D_2F(0,0,1)) = 3 \neq 0$, right?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What is $D_2F$? You should be able to answer my question above at any point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Comment: $JF(x,y,z) = [2xz\ 4y^3z\ x^2+y^4+3z^2]$ and $D_2F = [x^2+y^4+3z^2]$. Any point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ such that $F(x_0,y_0,z_0) = 0$, right? I am really confused.

Comment: I got it now. Every point $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in U \times f(U)$ satisfies $F(x_0,y_0,z_0) = 0$, and $x_0^2+y_0^4+3z_0^2 > 0$. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As usual, Ted gave a great answer (and you should accept it). I'll just nitpick a bit, which you might or might not appreciate now: being $C^1$ is a local property, so you want to check that given $(x_0,y_0)\in U$, then $f$ is of class $C^1$ in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$.

Great, so once you apply the IFT to the funcion $F$ in Ted's answer, you get a neighborhood $V$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ (which you can assume it's contained in $U$, replacing $V$ by $V\cap U$ if necessary) and an open interval $I$ centered in $z_0$ such that for all $(x,y) \in V$ there is a **unique** $\varphi(x,y)\in I$ such that $$F(x,y,\varphi(x,y))=1, $$and this implicit function $\varphi:V\to I$ is also $C^1$. By the **uniqueness** above, $f|_V= \varphi$ is $C^1$. And that's the reason $f$ is $C^1$. I just wanted to ilustrate the importance of the uniqueness part of the theorem, so you can use its full power without missing anything.

Comment: Good point, Ivo. I didn't specifically say that we were given that $f$ was defined (and continuous) on all of $U$, so the local solution is in fact global on $U$.

Comment: By  IFT $f$ is of class $C^1$ only in an open $V \subset U$, not on all of U. I don't see how can I get $f$ of class $C^1$ in $U$

Comment: Again: being $C^1$ is a local property, that is, $f$ is $C^1$ on $V$ if and only if each point in $V$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $f|_U$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Sorry being late, but it seems to me that the continuity of $f$ is an useless hypothesis since by your answer I can guarantee automatically that $f \in C^1(U)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Looking quickly it seems that you're right.